# Invoking Powershell from Java is executes infinate

Tags: java, eclipse, powershell, command

I am trying to invoke powershell commands from java program and i am able to achieve it with below code. But the problem is code wont stop after the execution of the powershell command.

This code prints the powershell command output . but it is executing infinate[execution not stoping after printing output].

Does anyone know what is the bug here ?

Java code :

```
public class PowerShellHelper 
{
public ProcessBuilder processbuilder = null; 
public Process process = null;

public PowerShellHelper() 
{

}

String execPowerShell()
{   
    String command = "Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -filter ProcessId=5988";
    String[] cmds = {"powershell.exe",command};
    String result= null;
    try
    {
        processbuilder = new ProcessBuilder(cmds);
        processbuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);           
        process = processbuilder.start();
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String line = null ;
        while (true)
        {                        
            line = r.readLine();
            if(line == null) {break;}
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        process.getOutputStream().close();

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception "+e);
    }
    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    PowerShellHelper psh  = new PowerShellHelper();
    psh.execPowerShell();   
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add:

```
process.getOutputStream().close();
```

after opening BufferedReader. 
This should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks a Ton!!
It worked. But i dint get the logic behind this , can you please let me know what is the trick here ?

Comment: Of course - when opening powershell process it waits for your input (some commands to execute). That prevents BufferedReader from returning NULL as process is still working (and some input still can be generated). By closing OutputStream you just make powershell to exit and let BufferedReader know that no more input will be generated.